# GULP [Browsersync] Couldn't open browser

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-browser-sync, windows64

Problem - When I run gulp, this message appears:

`[Browsersync] Couldn't open a browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)`

gulpfile.js code:

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    open: 'external',
    proxy: 'site1.net', // baseDir: "./"
    watchTask: true,
    port: 8080,
    browser: "chrome"
  });
});
```

I have to manually input the URLs into the browser & it worked with my current connections, but the message is still there. So how do I solve this issue? Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks

Screenshots:

http://www.screencast.com/t/rZDYsPLvM1uv

http://www.screencast.com/t/6MMLk5gA

http://www.screencast.com/t/9EoNLhAlK

*(note: sorry can't make hyperlink syntax work after many attempts, which is weird.)*

History:

I had no issues with my Browser sync before & my gulp runs automatically - not until now. I think I had Windows 10 64bit update today and this issue came out. All seems normal, except the Browser sync Issue.

I tried these links, but nothing seemed to work:

[BrowserSync Gulp doesn't open in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430871/browsersync-gulp-doesnt-open-in-chrome)

[Browser not launching with BrowserSync or live-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685783/browser-not-launching-with-browsersync-or-live-server)

Comment: What does the rest of your gulpfile.js look like? When I used your configuration for browsersync, I didn't have any issues.

Comment: @jstoobz FYI, I did not touch my gulpfile.js for almost a month with no problems & the issue happened just today, but since you asked, here it is https://github.com/raymacz/Gulpfile-Sass-/blob/master/Gulpfile.js

Comment: Probably something is wrong with your chrome path. I am not sure but try reinstalling it.

Comment: @harsimarriar96 I have tried it with Firefox, still the same issue.  When I use the "run" desktop windows app, it launches Chrome with no problems.  Even the directory path is correct, but I will try your advice.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Try running with default settings, @RayMacz, don't give custom fields for external port etc.

Comment: @harsimarriar96 Thanks, I already tried your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

running [ 64bit] windows 10

`Node [ v6.12.2 ]
Npm [ 3.10.10 ]
Gulp [ Local version 3.9.1 ]`

I upgraded my node & npm to:

`Node [ v8.11.3 ]
Npm [ 6.2.0 ]
Gulp [ Local version 3.9.1 ]`

when I ran "gulp", it suggested to do the ff commands:

```
      npm rebuild node-sass --force  // somehow node_modules (folder) was deleted
      npm install                    // reinstall node_modules (folder)
      npm audit
      npm audit fix
```

from here, when I ran "gulp", everything was running smoothly with no issues...

If somehow nothing works, you could check this from 
 [BrowserSync](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/1581)