# Trying to start server with Gulp and it throw error

Tags: gulp, gulp-4

I'm trying to run sever and I get this assertion error. I've uninstalled node and NPM and reinstalled again also I tried many steps and suggested solutions here but it doesn't fit with my problem.

```
AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: node_modules/scss/bootstrap.scss
        at getFunction (C:\Users\Saviour\Desktop\Portfolio\Bootstrap\Project1\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\normalizeArgs.js:15:5)
        at map (C:\Users\Saviour\Desktop\Portfolio\Bootstrap\Project1\node_modules\arr-map\index.js:20:14)
        at normalizeArgs (C:\Users\Saviour\Desktop\Portfolio\Bootstrap\Project1\node_modules\undertaker\lib\helpers\normalizeArgs.js:22:10)
        at Gulp.series (C:\Users\Saviour\Desktop\Portfolio\Bootstrap\Project1\node_modules\undertaker\lib\series.js:13:14)
        at C:\Users\Saviour\Desktop\Portfolio\Bootstrap\Project1\gulpfile.js:7:26
        at sass (C:\Users\Saviour\Desktop\Portfolio\Bootstrap\Project1\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:13:15)
        at bound (domain.js:422:14)
        at runBound (domain.js:435:12)
        at asyncRunner (C:\Users\Saviour\Desktop\Portfolio\Bootstrap\Project1\node_modules\async-done\index.js:55:18)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

This's my code

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass = require('gulp-sass');


gulp.task('sass', async function () {
    return gulp.src(gulp.series('node_modules/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'))
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});


gulp.task('js', async function () {
    return gulp.src(gulp.series('node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 'node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('src/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});


gulp.task('serve', async function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: "./src",
    });
    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], 'sass');
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
})


gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('sass', 'js', 'serve')));
```

Comment: after following what Sam said i faced this error Error: watching node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss,src/scss/*.scss: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series) at Gulp.watch (C:\Users\Saviour\Desktop\Portfolio\Bootstrap\Project1\node_modules\gulp\index.js:31:11) at C:\Users\Saviour\Desktop\Portfolio\Bootstrap\Project1\gulpfile.js:25:10 at serve

Comment: Second crack of the whip — Hey Alaa, I’ve updated my answer for you, basically as the error is saying you must alway wrap tasks in either `series` or `parallel` even if it is just one task! I’ve actually ran the updated version of the code and it worked without error.

Comment: Finally i made work after correcting  gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], gulp.series('sass'));  and the last thing i'm struggling in [Browsersync] Couldn't open browser (if you are using BrowserSync in a headless environment, you might want to set the open option to false)

Comment: There are a few answers already on stackoverflow for that problem. I would start by adding this `browser: 'chrome'` to your `browserSync.init({` Alternatively look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44432953/browser-sync-headless-environment-error or maybe this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685783/browser-not-launching-with-browsersync-or-live-server/42845813#42845813

Comment: I already tried this and more with no changes browserSync.init({
        port: 3001,
        server: {
            baseDir: "./src",
            open: true
        },
        watchTask: true,
        browser: "chrome.exe",
        notify: false
    });

Comment: Sorry Alaa, without more info I was just making a stab in the dark! This additional problem is really beyond the scope of your original question. I would recommend trying what your error message suggests and setting `open: false`, terminal will display a link to your server if that works. If it doesn’t, it would be best to create another question specifically about that problem with details of your setup. Eg: your os & its version and the package.json with the versions of the packages your running, also might be worth throwing in node/npm & browser versions plus any unusal setup! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from the `sass` and `js` tasks. You are wrapping your sources in `gulp.series`. So Gulp is trying to run your sources as tasks.

They just need to be in an array `[]` like in the watch task.

Just change:

`gulp.task('sass', async function () {
    return gulp.src(gulp.series('node_modules/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'))`

to:

`gulp.task('sass', async function () {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])`

and then the same format in the `js` task

---

The second error (coming from your watch task) is because you need to wrap the tasks you are watching in either `series` or `parallel`. **Even when theres only one task** So change:

`gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], 'sass');`

to:

`gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], gulp.series('sass'));`

Comment: I did actually like what you said and it throws this Error: watching node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss,src/scss/*.scss: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)
    at Gulp.watch (C:\Users\Saviour\Desktop\Portfolio\Bootstrap\Project1\node_modules\gulp\index.js:31:11)
    at C:\Users\Saviour\Desktop\Portfolio\Bootstrap\Project1\gulpfile.js:25:10
    at serve